# Fixing Javascript animation timings in inactive tabs with real time fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, settimeout

So I have a fiddle with two pulsing animations running at different times.

http://jsfiddle.net/JuFxn/16/

The code for the pulse is here. There is more in the fiddle so please check it out.

```
function fadeItIn() {
var child;

child = 4;
setTimeout(fadeIn, 3000);

function fadeIn() {
    $("#child" + child).fadeIn(175);
    --child;
    if (child >= 0) {
        // Continue fading in
        setTimeout(fadeIn, 175);
    } else {
        // Start fading out
        ++child;
        setTimeout(fadeOut, 175);
    }
}

function fadeOut() {
    $("#child" + child).fadeOut(175);
    ++child;
    if (child <= 4) {
        // Continue fading out
        setTimeout(fadeOut, 175);
    } else {
        // Start over again
        setTimeout(fadeIn, 3000 - 1575);
    }
}
}
```

The issue I'm having is that when the tab becomes inactive, the timings of the two pulses desync and go off pretty far from each other. I did some research and found this

[How can I make setInterval also work when a tab is inactive in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome)

They seem to fix the problem by implementing a real world counter in and adding the value of the counter during each cycle and having the div move based on the distance generated by the counter. Would implementing something like that fix the problem I am having? How would I even use it? I think the problem is arising from the use of the setTimeout on the second function.

```
setTimeout(fadeItInDoom, 500);
```

If I take out the setTimeout and make it so the two pulses execute at the same time, the timings never go off.

Comment: Timers in javascript are not reliable and don't necessarily reflect clock time, so it will be near impossible (if not outright impossible) to get two timers to stay in sync. It might be helpful for you to read this article: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up figuring out a fix to make it stay in sync.

http://jsfiddle.net/bwCmk/

I changed the animation code entirely so that it is running in jQuery. The fix however comes in how I dealt with changing to the next animation. I just made a different function for each pulsing element and had the next one called at the end of the previous function. So:

```
FunctionA {
    code
    functionB();
}
FunctionB {
    code
    functionC();
}
etc
```

it worked. Just putting this up so that if anyone else makes something along these lines, they can find a fix for it. Thanks to everyone who answered.